# Cannot create django test database

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I have a projects with hundreds of migrations. When I try to run the tests it gives me the stacktrace:

```
./manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 326, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "USING": syntax error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 29, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 62, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 601, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 546, in setup_databases
    self.parallel, **kwargs
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 187, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get('TEST', {}).get('SERIALIZE', True),
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 69, in create_test_db
    run_syncdb=True,
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 131, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail_modeltranslation/management/commands/migrate_translation.py", line 25, in handle
    super(Command, self).handle(*args, **options)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/special.py", line 108, in database_forwards
    self._run_sql(schema_editor, self.sql)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/special.py", line 133, in _run_sql
    schema_editor.execute(statement, params=None)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 136, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 326, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "USING": syntax error
```

From this alone I cannot seem to figure out the cause (which probably is a migration somewhere).
When I try to run the same command using a postgres database, I get a error

```
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 29, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 62, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 601, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 546, in setup_databases
    self.parallel, **kwargs
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 187, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get('TEST', {}).get('SERIALIZE', True),
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 69, in create_test_db
    run_syncdb=True,
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 131, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/wagtail_modeltranslation/management/commands/migrate_translation.py", line 25, in handle
    super(Command, self).handle(*args, **options)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 221, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 531, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 112, in _alter_field
    new_db_params, strict,
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 635, in _alter_field
    new_default = self.effective_default(new_field)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 245, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 770, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 762, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1043, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1036, in to_python
    params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'N' value must be either True or False."]
```

Since I use the value `N` all over the project, this does not help much either.
How do I go about finding the migration that causes these errors?

Comment: In both cases, `wagtail_modeltranslation` seems to be involved when the `migrate_translation` command is ran. You might want to check if the version of `modeltranslation` you're using is compatible with your current Django version. Also, does this error happen right at the start or after some of the migrations have run, in which case you might want to take a look at the last migration that is run before the error occurs.

Comment: `wagtail_modeltranslation` is compatible, and was the first probable issue I've investigated. But the developers themselves seem to think that it does not have to do with `wagtail_modeltranslation` https://github.com/infoportugal/wagtail-modeltranslation/issues/175#issuecomment-414359570

Comment: `python manage.py test -v 2` will show you which migrations are being applied, or `--verbosity=2`. If not, try `-v 3`

Comment: @dirkgroten Exactly what I was looking for! If you could post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the `--verbosity` of `-v` option when running your tests, which adds more verbosity to the output of your tests:

```
python manage.py test -v 2
```

or

```
python manage.py test --verbosity=2
```

Level 2 should show you all the migrations. Level 3 even shows more details, but I don't think it'll add much in your case.

This will show you which migration is causing the issue.